# STL-compliant memory allocator library

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost, stl

I need to use a `map`, with keys as `uint32_t` and values as `Meshes`. I want the meshes to be layed out in contigous memory for performance, as they will be accessed very often in succession.

I am wondering what memory-allocator libraries are available that provides the following aswell;

- Allocates to contigous memory space
- Preferably handles fragmentation of said memory space
- As fast as possible and as little additional features as possible besides what I mentioned

I've looked at boost, but it dosn't seem to provide what I'm looking for.

(Reason I'm not using `vector` is that the container will grow and shrink alot, and I prefer to have a `uint32_t` as the identifier for a `mesh`)

Thanks

Comment: wouldn't you consider writing your own, specially fit for your use case?

Comment: In *what* succession exactly? Map order?

Comment: The allocator doesn't get the information from `map` for which element it shall allocate. That is, you can create the elements in contiguous storage, but you cannot influence the memory order of the elements (and this will probably hurt locality/iteration speed). You could store indices or iterators in the map that point into a vector or deque. This way, you'd have contiguous storage (vector) plus `uint32_t` keys.

Answer (score -1):

Deque

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/

Nothing else much to say.  Go read about it.

Comment: Except that meets neither the requirement to be an allocator for a map, nor to use contiguous memory.